# Question on Pauli's Exclusion Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, atomic-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

Pauli's EP says that electrons in a subshell will have opposing spins.

Now, lets say I prepare two electrons with spin up. If I took an alpha particle ($\mathrm{He^{2+}}$) and added one of these electrons I would have a $\mathrm{He^+}$ ion with an electron with a spin up. If I were to add the second electron to this ion which of the following would happen?

1. The electron being added would change to spin down and become part of the atom forming $\mathrm{He}$.
2. The electron previously added would change to spin down and the new one would stay spin up, forming $\mathrm{He}$.
3. The new electron would get repelled and the ion would remain as $\mathrm{He^+}$.

I'm really curious as to what would happen! :)

Answer (score 6):

The options 1,2 are actually physically identical because the electrons are identical particles. Once we have two electrons, we can't say which of them is "Paul" and which of them is "Peter".

When the addition is slow etc., the option 1=2 violates the conservation law for the angular momentum. So it is indeed 3 that has to happen: the ion will refuse to "accept" another electron with the same spin.

The reason why the electron won't be accepted is sometimes called a force, the Pauli force, although it is not a genuine force in the sense that it would be given by an extra term in the Hamiltonian.

Comment: So if the addition is fast enough then the spin should change?

Comment: If the addition is such that there's a significant probability that the new electron carries some (orbital) angular momentum, then the absorption may occur, and the change the two electrons' spin may be attributed to the change of the angular momentum. Also note that there's an energy conservation law. So the new electron has to have the right energy to be absorbed at any case. If it has too big an energy, the absorption of the new electron may occur, but the newly born helium atom has to emit a particle, most likely a photon. The photon may carry the angular momentum as well.

Comment: So with the emission of the extra photon that carries the excessive energy away, one may have a process that deals with the problem of the wrong angular momentum, too.

Comment: So then it is not possible to control which electron is the one that changes its spin?

Comment: It is not possible to control "which" electron does anything because it is not possible to determine which electron is which in general, so claiming that you did something to a particular one and not the other would be physically meaningless. When you calculate the probability of processes, you must include histories without as well as with the permutations of the electrons, and only the sum may be interpreted as a probability amplitude that something happens. If the electrons are in the same atom, they are indistinguishable even in practice "by location", which would be possible otherwise.

Comment: Surely the ion could "accept" the extra electron, just in a higher orbital, the lowest compatible with conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: Yup, this is possible and an excellent intermediate state for a final state I mentioned. When an electron is caught by a higher orbital, it is unstable, and will eventually fall to the twice 1s helium ground state, while emitting some photon  or photons.

Comment: Well this answers most of my question about adding electrons to a hydride ion. I wonder why the mods closed my question as unclear? Anyway, I go further by showing quantum unreality gets real not after measurement but during entanglement. The spin of each electron goes from up AND down to up OR down so if one escapes and is measured as down, the other has already been set as up during the entanglement. The measurement of the external electron did not instantaneously set the still bound electron up.

Comment: The refusal to accept another electron of the same spin means the electrons are not identical. Otherwise, if electrons can re-write each others spin, they would not be able to reject electrons of the same spin. Sure, once they're in the orbital, it doesn't matter if they're identical or not.

Comment: Sorry ralfcis but your reasoning about "Pauli implies not identical" is clearly logically faulty. The Fermi-Dirac statistics does assume that they are always identical, but their occupation number in a precise state is always 0 or 1. There is absolutely no contradiction between these two statements. Identical particles means that only the number of particles of the given type in a precisely determine one-particle state is what specifies a multiparticle state. Pauli principle says that the occupation number cannot be above 1. Both follow from anticommuting field operators.